# No funciona la query de mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

La query no me funciona. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
update users set hasCredit = 1 where users.id = (select users.id from users inner join creditRequest on (users.id = creditRequest.user_id))
```

Comment: Podrías indicar para claridad de la pregunta que es lo que quieres lograr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es necesario hacer esa subquery con un `JOIN`, bastaría con revisar la existencia en la tabla `CreditRequest` o usar `IN`:

```
update users 
set hasCredit = 1 
where id in (select user_id from credtRequest)
```

O con `EXISTS`:

```
update users 
set hasCredit = 1 
where exists(select 1 from credtRequest
             WHERE credtRequest.user_id = users.id)
```

Comment: Genial! Muchas gracias